# Finding f(g(h(x)))=g(h(f(x)))

Tags: functions

This may be a silly question but I was curious if it was possible to find a series of algorithms that would satisfy the property of f(g(h(x)))=g(h(f(x)))

For context I’m attempting to determine a method to pass an input from function to function that would result in the same output regardless of order of the functions. I.E
f(x)=a, g(a)=h has to equal g(x)=b, f(b)=h, so f(g(x))= g(f(x))

I’m not super mathematically accurate so I don’t know if there’s a name for this property or even if it translates up, so sorry if this is a bad question.

Comment: Is your question about general functions, do you have specific algorithms in mind or do you just want to know if such functions exist? The answer to the last option is yes, consider for example the functions $\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z$ where $f(x) = 2x, g(x)=3x, h(x)=4x$...

Comment: Well essentially I want to solve for a series of inequalities that satisfies the following: f(x) > 0,
f(f(x)) > 0,
g(f(x)) = f(g(x)) < 0,
g(f(f(x))) = f(g(f(x))) = f(f(g(x))) > 0,
h(x) < 0,
f(h(x)) = h(f(x)) < 0,
f(g(h(x))) = g(f(h(x))) = h(f(g(x))) > 0,
f(f(g(h(x)))) = g(f(f(h(x)))) < 0,